# ASP.NET/IIS request processing. Who spawns threads?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have been trying to understand the way IIS works with ASP.NET. One of the most intriguing questions that comes to my mind is: when there are simultaneous (concurrent) requests for an asp.net page, does IIS spawn threads or does ASP.NET spawn threads or do both spawn threads to process the requests?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you should understand it as ASP.NET does the heavy lifting, as detailed in KB821268,

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821268

The integrated pipeline of IIS 7 and above makes things even more complicated, as documented in the blog post,

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2007/07/21/asp-net-thread-usage-on-iis-7-0-and-6-0.aspx

Comment: the second link made sense. I could understand how ASP.net uses threads